# If $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ is transitive then are $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ always transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, relations

If $\mathcal U$ is a not empty relation in a set $X$ and $\mathcal V$ is a not empty relation in a set $Y$ then it is usual to put
$$
\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V:=\big\{\big((a,b),(p,q)\big)\in(X\times Y)\times(X\times Y):(a\mathcal U p)\wedge(b\mathcal V q)\big\}
$$
Now let's we assume that $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ are transitive. So if $\big((a,b),(p,q)\big)$ and $\big((p,q),(h,k)\big)$ are in $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ then $(a,p)$ and $(p,h)$ are in $\mathcal U$ whereas $(b,q)$ and $(q,k)$ are in $\mathcal V$ so that by transitivity $(a,h)$ is in $\mathcal U$ and $(b,k)$ in $\mathcal V$ and thus $\big((a,b),(h,k)\big)$ is in $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$: we conclude that $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ is transitive.

Now assuming $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ is transitive then I expected that even $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ were transitive but unfortunately I was not able to prove it so that I thought to put here a specific question where I ask to prove or disprove (with a counterexample) this. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What if $\mathcal{U}$ is not transitive and $\mathcal{V}$ is the empty relation? The product is vacuously transitive.

Comment: Okay, and if $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ are not empty?

Comment: Same idea. $\mathcal{U}$ is transitive and $\mathcal{V}$ does not contain any triple $(r,s,t)$ such that $r\mathcal{V}s$ and $s\mathcal{V}t$. The product is vacuously transitive.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand: could you explain better, please?

Comment: If the relation $\mathcal{V}$ is such that no element of $Y$ occurs on both the right and left side of it. In other words, if $L:Y\times Y\to Y$ is the projection $L(y_1,y_2)=y_1$ and $R:Y\times Y\to Y$ is the projection $R(y_1,y_2)=y_2$, then the condition is that the ranges $L(\mathcal{V})$ and $R(\mathcal{V})$ are disjoint.

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo. It should have been the ranges of $\mathcal{V}$ under the projections.

Comment: I am still confused, sorry: I know that if $\mathcal V$ is a relation in $Y$ then it is contained into $Y\times Y$ so that the sets $L(\mathcal V)$ and $R(\mathcal V)$ are not empty but I do not understand what happens when they are disjoint.

Comment: Then $\mathcal{U}*\mathcal{V}$ will be transitive for any $\mathcal{U}$, even if $\mathcal{U}$ is not transitive.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see this now: are you able to prove it?

Comment: In order for a relation $T$ on a set $S$ not to be transitive, there must be $a,b,c\in S$ such that $aTb$ and $bTc$, but not $aTc$. In this case, $b\in L(T)\cap R(T)$. By contraposition, if $L(T)\cap R(T)=\varnothing$, there can't be any such $a,b,c$ to make $T$ non-transitive. If $L(\mathcal{V})\cap R(\mathcal{V})=\varnothing$, then the same will be true of the product.

Comment: So if $\big((a,b),(p,q)\big)$ and $\big((p,q),(h,k)\big)$ are in $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ then $(p,q)$ and $(q,k)$ are in $\mathcal V$ so that $q$ would be into $R(\mathcal V)$ and into $L(\mathcal V)$ so that if these two sets are disjoint then for any $(a,b)$ and $(h,k)$ there is not $(p,q)$ as above and so $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ is vacuously transitive, right?

Comment: That should be $\mathcal{U}*\mathcal{V}$ in the last line, but otherwise yes.

Comment: Anyway we now proved that if $L(\mathcal V)$ and $R(\mathcal V)$ are disjoint then $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ is transitive when $\mathcal U$ is not so that the statement of question is false since if it was true then $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ was transitive iff $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ were transitive but we disproved this, right?

Comment: That's correct. However, if $L(\mathcal{V})\cap R(\mathcal{V})\neq \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{U}*\mathcal{V}$ is transitive, then $\mathcal{U}$ must be transitive.

Comment: So if $L(\mathcal V)\cap R(\mathcal V)$ are not disjoint then there exists $\theta$ there contained and so there exists $p$ and $q$ in $Y$ such that $(\theta,p)$ and $(q,\theta)$ are in $\mathcal V$, right? So why this implies transitivity of $\mathcal U$?

Comment: So if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are in $\mathcal U$ then $\big((a,q),(b,\theta)\big)$ and $\big((b,\theta),(c,p)\big)$ are in $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ (right?) and thus by transitivity $\big((a,q),(c,p)\big)$ is in $\mathcal U\ast\mathcal V$ so that $(a,c)$ is in $\mathcal U$, right?